# Trying to solve the Lyapunov candidate, but having trouble with some of the steps.

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, stability-in-odes, lyapunov-functions

I have this state model: $$\dot{x_1}=-x_1+{x_1}^3+2x_2$$
$$\dot{x_2}=-x_2-x_1^3$$

My Lyapunov candidate is $$x^TPx $$
where P is $$\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\1 & 3\end{bmatrix} $$

I know that $$\dot{V}(x)=\dot{x}^TPx+x^TP\dot{x}=2x^TP\dot{x}$$

I don't know how to procede from here, so if anyone could give me a clue or hint, that would be very much appreciated.

Edit:

So I managed to solve this by solving this step first:

$$\dot{V}(x)=\dot{x}^TPx+x^TP\dot{x}=2x^TP\dot{x}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1 & x_2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\1 & 3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\dot{x}_1\\ \dot{x}_2\end{bmatrix}$$

Then I was able to show, by solving the Lyapunov candidate, that the origin is asymptotically stable.

Comment: Where is the higher order?

Comment: I've editet my question. Hopefully it is clearer now. And I was also able to solve it. So I've added som new information to the question.

Comment: That is the right way to do it, yes...